# How can I extract a given cell position?

Tags: python, xlrd

I want to extract the position of a given cell from an excel table.

```
for row in range(rows):
   for col in range(cols):
     thecell = sheet.cell(row, col)
     ertek = thecell.value
     if thecell.value == "Size":
        print thecell.coordinate
```

I tried coordinate but it says:

> AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'coordinate'

Comment: Is rows a 2d array or some custom data structure?

Comment: no, its in excel table structure

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_file_name.xls')
```

If your file has non-ASCII characters, you should open it in the unicode format as follows:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_file_name.xls', encoding='cp1252')
```

If your spreadsheet is very large, you can add an argument on_demand to open_workbook, which loads only current sheets to memory:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_file_name.xls', on_demand = True)
```

Opening a sheet
If you know the name of the sheet, you can open it by running the following:

```
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('My_Sheet_Name')
```

If you are not sure of the name of the sheet, you can open the first worksheet by its index:

```
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

workbook.nsheets wants to know the number of sheets. workbook.sheet_names() gives you a list of the names of the sheets present in the file, which helps you iterate over the sheets.

Getting data from cells
Once you have selected the worksheet, you can extract the value of a particular data cell as follows.

## Value of 1st row and 1st column

```
sheet.cell(0, 0).value
```

You can iterate it over a loop to extract data in the whole sheet.

You can detect an empty cell by using empty_cell in xlrd.

```
if sheet.cell(0, 0).value == xlrd.empty_cell.value:
    # Do something
```

OR SKIP ALL THE ABOVE AND YOU CAN DO THIS -->

you can simply

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame('yourexcelpath/filename.xlsx')
```

Perform operations on this dataframe and then export it to excel again.

```
df.to_excel(exportpathname+"\\"+"filename.xlsx", index=False)
```

Vote up if this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: thank You very much, but I need the position of a known cell. So first I look for the cell that contains "Size:" and after I want to get where it is. So in format like 'A13' or row = 0 and col =23

Comment: if sheet.cell(0,x).value == 'Size': store this x value. , use global variable or return this. and just add 1 to switch it to next row.